# Get diff of request in redis

Tags: redis

Is it possible to get the diff between the state before and after a request, for simplified execution?

For a simple request it sounds superfluous, but on a e.g. transaction it makes more sense.
For example you can do a request like this:

```
if key ASD is present set value of ASD to 23 and increment ABC by 5
```

The expected diff might be smth like:

```
SET ASD 23
SET ABC 6
```

Or

```
None
```

Comment: You can write a Lua script to implement your example.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?